# Javascript sorted lists

Tags: javascript, list, sorting

Is there a sorted list in Javascript or jQuery?

I have a huge list with few insert actions over time.
I cannot afford to call object.sort() for the entire list each time I add a single item.
I need an insert of o(log(n));

Comment: If you're talking about a native type, then no, JavaScript does not have this feature, though there's no reason why you can't do this yourself. Alternatively, have a look at [this technique](http://blog.vjeux.com/2009/javascript/speed-up-javascript-sort.html) to speed up `Array.sort` (there's no such thing as `Object.sort`)

Comment: This is for node.js, but with some very minor tweaking could be your solution: https://github.com/shinout/SortedList

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't, all you have is `Array#sort` which you've ruled out using repeatedly (and with good reason!). You'll have to use an [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) approach.

Comment: From your link: _It is much less efficient on large lists_

Comment: However, it also states that it's "efficient for data sets that are already substantially sorted".

Comment: @mplungjan: My impression was that the data set was already sorted, and so the OP was looking for a solution to avoid doing a full re-sort on insertion. Insertions sorts aren't a great answer for the *initial* sort of a data set, but they're a great way to *keep* it sorted if you have relatively few insertions (or modifications involving the key, where you do a remove and re-insert). In fact, they can be very fast indeed for that part of it.

Comment: What I'm looking for is something like an AVL or a Red-Black tree as are supplied in Java(TreeMap) and C++(std::map<>). These data structures remain constantly sorted even when they are constantly changed. Is there something similar in JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: @eshalev: *"What I'm looking for is something like an AVL or a Red-Black tree... Is there something similar in JavaScript or jQuery?"* Not in JavaScript itself, no, nothing *sorted*. (The implementation of objects on any decent platform will use an efficient map, which may well be in one of those forms, for property lookups.) Someone may well have built one, but I don't specifically know of any. *(cont'd)*

Comment: @eshalev: *(continuing)* You might find that `Array` is pretty much what you want, but it'll depend entirely on your situation. `Array` instances in JavaScript are **not** like the contiguous-block-of-memory "array" from languages like C or Java. They're actually just objects, and they use the same underlying property lookup as objects. (Array indexes are actually strings like all other property names, not numbers, not that any of us writes them that way.) So since array indexes are really property names... *(cont'd)*

Comment: @eshalev: *(continuing)* ...they should be using the same (optimized) key lookup (which may well use a balanced tree or similar) that other object properties do. Note that if you insert into a JavaScript `Array`, it *doesn't* have to move a bunch of memory around; all it does is change the affected property keys assigned to the entries in the array. The `Array#splice` method can be used to insert into an array or to remove entries from an array, and since this method is provided by the JavaScript interpreter, it's free to optimize how it applies to `Array` instances. *(cont'd)*

Comment: @eshalev: *(continuing)* Anyway, you'd have to do profiling on your target JavaScript implementations to make sure the performance characteristics suit you, since implementations are free to optimize anything they like, provided they adhere to the specification about the *externally* facing aspects.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: So adding an object at index #101 in a 2000 element array does not involve changing elements 102-2000?

Comment: @eshalev: If you do `theArray[100] = newValue;`, no other elements at all are affected; you're just setting a property named "100" to the new value (changing rather than inserting). If you do `theArray.splice(100, 0, newValue);` (inserting at index 100) then the JavaScript runtime will update the property names on the existing properties "100", "101", ..., "1999" to be "101", "102", ..., "2000", and then put the new value on property "100". That update happens entirely within the runtime, and so *can* be optimized (whether it *is* or not depends on the implementation).

Comment: Then this is no good for me, because on list of size N inserting one element would involve changing N keys making it o(N)